# gfortran WRITE and FORMAT not appearing to need to conform on intel comiler

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am compiling a program which is known to compile with `ifort` using `gfortran`. However, the compiler fails on the line

```
WRITE (11,1325) ((IFILE,FILENAME(IFILE)),IFILE=1,IFILES)
```

with the compile error:

```
main_file.f:205.32:

     WRITE (11,1325) ((IFILE,FILENAME(IFILE)),IFILE=1,IFILES)       
                            1
Error: Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant at (1)
make: *** [main_file.o] Error 1
```

Changing this line to (note removal of '(' and ')')

```
WRITE (11,1480) (IFILE,FILENAME(IFILE),IFILE=1,IFILES)
```

to match the subsequent line

```
1480      FORMAT (1X,I1,' ',A40)
```

solves the problem, but I was wondering if anyone may know why is this mistake not captured by the Intel compiler. In this instance, it seems to be `gfortran` which is giving the correct behaviour. My compile flags are:

```
gfortran -fno-automatic -mcmodel=medium -O2 -ffast-math  main_file.o -o main_file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite an interesting issue. It works only for arrays:

```
 print *, ((1,["a","b"]),i=1,10)
end
```

works, but

```
 print *, ((1,"a"),i=1,10)
end
```

fails with ifort:

```
: error #6063: An INTEGER or REAL data type is required in this context.   ['a']
 print *, ((1,"a"),i=1,10)
```

God knows what the parser thinks it is in the first working case, maybe an incomplete nested implied do? For sure it is not legal Fortran syntax and should by refused by compiler which requires standard Fortran. Intel may have reasons to accept this syntax.

Comment: Hello again Vladimir! Thanks for the quickly posted comment. Yes, this is my first detailed exposure to Fortran and it appears to me to have an amazing about of quirks for a mature language.

Answer (score 1):

As others have posted in the similar recent questions, due to its heritage the Intel compiler allows a number of extensions by default.  The compiler will emit a diagnostic if you supply the appropriate standard check option (`/stand` on Windows, for example).

I'm not sure of the specific source of this particular extension, but it covers a somewhat occasional syntax misunderstanding, where people would put the "arguments" to the write or read "function" in parentheses...

```
READ (*,*) (not_valid_syntax)
```

(In a write statement an expression in parentheses is itself an expression, and that is a valid output list item - a few years back the Intel compiler would get a bit confused about that.)

Comment: Cheers Ian, yeah, it seems the combination of old FORTRAN and an alternative new compiler has raised a number of quirks. As a non FORTRAN programmer I'm beginning to see why it's fallen out of favour despite its speed.

Comment: Your original code is not, and never was, "true" Fortran, as defined by any of the various Fortran standards.  It uses compiler specific extensions.  That the use of extensions to a standard language may cause problems when you change compiler is hardly a Fortran specific issue.  Portability between compilers is the reason standards exist - if programmers don't stick to them, they get what they deserve.